# Given $f(x+y)=f(x)f(y), f'(0)=11,f(3)=3$, what is $f'(3)$?

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, functions, proof-verification, functional-equations

The question is this:

> Given
>   \begin{align}
> f(x+y)&=f(x)f(y)\\
> f'(0)&=11\\
> f(3)&=3
> \end{align}
>   What is $f'(3)$?

And my solution:

On differentiating the equation $f(x+y)=f(x)f(y)$ wrt $x$ we get:

$$f'(x+y)(1+y')=f(x)f'(y)(y') + f'(x)f(y)$$

Now on substituting $x=0$ and $y=3$, we get :

$$f'(3)(1+0)=f(0)f'(3)0 + f(3)f'(0)$$

$$f'(3)=3\times11=33$$

Is this a correct way to solve the problem?

Comment: Since you are differentiating with respect to $x$, $y$ is a constant. Thus, differentiating $f(x+y)=f(x)f(y)$ yields
$$
f'(x+y)=f'(x)f(y)
$$
which is essentially what you have done more explicitly when you use that $y'=0$.

Comment: Ok, if you say like this: *Since you are differentiating with respect to x, y is a constant*, then it seems convincing. But when we were discussing on this method of his, his reasoning was that y′ = 0 because after you substitute y=3, y is a constant. That created the whole confusion. Well, this is fine now.

Comment: @robjohn- thnx a lot!

Comment: See also: http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1454760/prove-that-f-x-f-0fx-derivatives

Answer (score 5):

Yes, that is a valid way to use the chain rule to get the answer.

Here is another approach.
$$
\begin{align}
f'(x)
&=\lim_{h\to0}\frac{f(x+h)-f(x)}{h}\\
&=\lim_{h\to0}\frac{f(x)f(h)-f(x)f(0)}{h}\\
&=f(x)\lim_{h\to0}\frac{f(h)-f(0)}{h}\\
&=f(x)f'(0)
\end{align}
$$
Thus, $f'(3)=f(3)f'(0)$.

Comment: This solution had already been known to him and me. But then he gave another way to solve the problem and I doubted it was wrong. So the question clearly states whether his solution is correct. Anyways, thanks for bringing it up here.

Comment: @ParthThakkar: fair enough. I've altered my answer to be an alternate answer :-)

Comment: But still, the hitch in the method given by @AkshayKrishnan is why should you say y' = 0 *AFTER* (I've been repeatedly emphasizing on this word) setting it to be a constant. This seems wrong to me.

Comment: @ParthThakkar: I have commented on the original post regarding that.

Comment: This method has the avantage of only assuming the differentiability of $f$ at $0$ and then prove that actually $f$ is differentiable everywhere. The OP's method assume $f$ to be differentiable at any point, fact which is not stated in the question.

Comment: @Taladris: Actually, I believe that the relation that $f(x+y)=f(x)f(y)$ in tandem with the chain rule implies that if $f$ is differentiable at $0$, it is differentiable everywhere. My proof is just on a more basic level.

Answer (score 1):

you cannot assume that y' at 0 will be zero

Comment: You see, that's what I've been having trouble with! His reasoning is, as he had told me earlier, is that $y'$ = 0 because after you substitute $y = 3$, y is a constant. Isn't that wrong?

Comment: y′ = 0 means y is to be differentiated first then you should put the value as 3 and calculate

Comment: it should be something like y'(3)

Comment: Exactly. That's what I've been trying to tell him, and everybody here, but it doesn't seem to have any effect.

Comment: @Bunny: $x$ is varying $y$ is constant. Therefore, $y'=0$. The formula $$f'(x+y)(1+y')=f(x)f'(y)(y') + f'(x)f(y)$$ is confusing in its generality, but it is correct and the fact that $y'=0$ is correct.

Comment: my dear friend you cannot say this by the function that y is constant (trust me). y is a function of x that can be true

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that $f$ has a derivative in $x=3$, then yes. In order to avoid all confusion induced by $y'$ (as show other comments/answers), you should start with simlpier line:

$$f(x+3)=3f(x)$$

and then take the derivative at $x=0$.

Comment: I doubt it. See, he got some equation after differentiating wrt x. In the equation there's a $y'$ term. AFTER that he is substituting $y = 3$, which is a constant and hence the $y'$ term will be zero anyways. That, to me, seems crooked.

Comment: @ParthThakkar If we assume that $f$ is differentiable, then the chain rule saves the day.

Comment: Um...this manipulation (removing y) seems to avoid all those two-variable-differentiation troubles, and I am fine with it. But I still don't get that AFTER substituting $y=$*a constant*, how can you put $y' = 0$. It's been bugging me for a while.

Comment: @ParthThakkar Take an arbitrary $y(x)\in\mathcal C^1$, apply chain rule, obtain a general result, then take a particular case $y(x)=3$.