# Prove that $f′(x)=f′(0)f(x)$ derivatives

Tags: calculus, derivatives, functional-equations

Let $f:I \to R$ be differrentiable on an open interval $I \subseteq R$ with

$$f(a + b) = f(a)f(b) \quad \forall a, b \in R$$

Suppose that $f(0) = 1$ and that $f'(0)$ exists. Show that:

$$f'(x) = f'(0)f(x) \quad \forall x \in R$$

So far, this is what I got:

$$  f(x+0)= f(x)f(0)$$
 $$f(x) = f(x)f(0)$$
For all $x$ , $f(0)$ has to be $1$.

$$0=f(x)f(0) - f(x)$$

$$0 = f(x)(f(0) -1)$$

$f(x)=0$ for all $x$ or $f(0) = 1$.

I'm stuck here. Could you please give a hint?

Comment: Use definition of derivative $$f'(x) = \lim_{h \to 0}\frac{f(x + h) - f(x)}{h}$$ and then use $f(x + h) = f(x)f(h)$.

Comment: It looks like there are redundant and confusing prerequisites. The prerequisite that $f$ is differentiable on an open interval $I\subseteq\mathbb R$ doesn't have to be used (it follows anyway). The notion that $f$ is defined on $I$ is confusing since $f(a+b)=f(a)f(b)\forall a, b\in\mathbb R$ suggests that $f$ is defined on all $\mathbb R$.

Comment: @kurtk3 When you've solved it you can confront him with the prerequisites that you have not used (either they're redundant or your solution is wrong). Perhaps he have another solution in mind that these are required prerequisites?

Comment: @skyking  then,,, should i have to show about continuity? actually i don't get that part.

Comment: @kurtk3 A function has to be continuous in order to be derivable (besides the question doesn't explicitely ask to prove continuity). Paramanand Singh's hint is enough to show what asked for (and as far as I can tell it will not explicitly use continuity).

Comment: I think the simplest approach would be to just apply the definition of the derivative along with the fact that $f(x+h) = f(x)f(h)$ for this particular function.

Comment: See also: http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/420225/given-fxy-fxfy-f0-11-f3-3-what-is-f3

Comment: @kurtk3 I have to admit that I am a bit surprised that you have [removed my edit](http://math.stackexchange.com/posts/1454760/revisions). Textual information is better than picture for searching and many other purposes. And I think that the title which includes the equation which your function has to fulfill describes the question better. (Informative titles [are encouraged](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/9959/how-to-ask-a-good-question/10144#10144).)

Comment: And - not surprisingly - another user has [now edited the text](http://math.stackexchange.com/review/suggested-edits/490318) instead of picture. Going back and forth with this basically means wasting the time of users which are helping you to improve your post.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I am expanding on my hint in the comment. The question is simpler than it appears. Moreover as others have pointed out the question gives more hypotheses than necessary to get to the conclusion.

The following is the corrected version without any redundant hypotheses:

*Let $f: \mathbb{R} \to \mathbb{R}$ be a function such that $f(a + b) = f(a)f(b)$ for all $a, b \in \mathbb{R}$. If $f'(0)$ exists then $f'(x) = f'(0)f(x)$ for all $x \in \mathbb{R}$.*

Since $f'(0)$ exists we have by definition of derivative $$\lim_{h \to 0}\frac{f(h) - f(0)}{h} = f'(0)\tag{1}$$ Now it is easily seen (again via definition of derivative) that
\begin{align}
f'(x) &= \lim_{h \to 0}\frac{f(x + h) - f(x)}{h}\notag\\
&= \lim_{h \to 0}\frac{f(x + h) - f(x + 0)}{h}\notag\\
&= \lim_{h \to 0}\frac{f(x)f(h) - f(x)f(0)}{h}\text{ (because }f(a + b) = f(a)f(b))\notag\\
&= \lim_{h \to 0}f(x)\cdot\frac{f(h) - f(0)}{h}\notag\\
&= f(x)f'(0)\text{ (using }(1))\notag
\end{align}
As you can see we don't need to know the value of $f(0)$. It is immaterial. However there are only two choices for $f(0)$. Either $f(0) = 0$ or $f(0) = 1$ and both are valid choices.

Answer (score 1):

Consider the map $g_y$, for a given $y$, $x\mapsto f(x+y)$.
Then, $g_y'(x) = f'(x+y)$.
But $g_y(x) = f(x)f(y)$, so $g_y'(x) = f'(x)f(y)$.

Thus, for $x=0$, $g_y'(0) = f'(y) = f'(0)f(y)$.

Comment: thank you, however, what do you think about this "It looks like there are redundant and confusing prerequisites. The prerequisite that ff is differentiable on an open interval I⊆RI⊆R doesn't have to be used (it follows anyway). The notion that ff is defined on II is confusing since f(a+b)=f(a)f(b)∀a,b∈Rf(a+b)=f(a)f(b)∀a,b∈R suggests that ff is defined on all R"

Comment: Skyding just wants to say that your hypothesis are weird. f is defined $I\to \mathbb R$, but then you say $f(x) \forall x\in \mathbb R$. Moreover, with Paramamand Singh solution, you don't need the hypothesis of differentiability of $f$ everywhere.